# Null object reference error when referencing member variable object with nested class

Tags: java, android, object, nested

I instantiate a "MwVolley" object in the `onCreate()` method of `ShareActivity`, reference it there, and later reference that object again in a nested class of `ShareActivity`.

So I declared this object as a member variable of `ShareActivity`:

```
protected MwVolley apiCall;
```

Then instantiated it by calling the constructor in `onCreate()`, and referenced it a few times:

```
    apiCall = new MwVolley(this);
    Log.d("Repeat", "Logging apiCall object in onCreate: " + apiCall.toString());

    if (filePath != null) {
        //extract the coordinates of image in decimal degrees
        Log.d("Image", "Calling GPSExtractor");
        GPSExtractor imageObj = new GPSExtractor(filePath);
        String coords = imageObj.getCoords();

        if (coords != null) {
            Log.d("Image", "Coords of image: " + coords);

            apiCall.setCoords(coords);
            //asynchronous calls to MediaWiki Commons API to match image coords with nearby Commons categories
            apiCall.request();
```

Then later on tried to reference it again in the nested class `ResponseListener`:

```
protected class ResponseListener<T> implements Response.Listener<T> {

    private final String TAG = ResponseListener.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onResponse(T response) {

        int currentRadius = apiCall.getRadius();
        int nextRadius = currentRadius * 10;

        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        Log.d("Repeat", "Logging apiCall object in ResponseListener: " + apiCall.toString());
        Log.d("Repeat", "categorySet contains: " + apiCall.categorySet.toString());

        if (nextRadius <= 10000 && apiCall.categorySet.size() <= 10) {

            apiCall.setRadius(nextRadius);
            Log.d("Repeat", "Repeating API call with radius " + Integer.toString(nextRadius));

            apiCall.request();

        }

        if (apiCall.getGpsCatExists() == true) {
            gpsItems = new ArrayList<String>(apiCall.getGpsCat());
            Log.d("Cat", "GPS items: " + gpsItems.toString());

        } else {
            gpsItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the error:

```
01-04 02:28:08.450: E/ACRA(4430): fr.free.nrw.commons fatal error : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int fr.free.nrw.commons.upload.MwVolley.getRadius()' on a null object reference
01-04 02:28:08.450: E/ACRA(4430): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int fr.free.nrw.commons.upload.MwVolley.getRadius()' on a null object reference
01-04 02:28:08.450: E/ACRA(4430):   at fr.free.nrw.commons.upload.ShareActivity$ResponseListener.onResponse(ShareActivity.java:227)
```

If I comment out `apiCall.getRadius()` and give it an arbitrary int, it proceeds there but then causes a null object reference error again at the next `apiCall` reference.

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought all nested classes can freely access member variables of their enclosing class, even private and protected ones. And I know the object was instantiated when I called the constructor in `onCreate()`, because I can log and reference the object there.

Unfortunately I can't paste the code for the entire `ShareActivity` class here (too long), but it's all on https://github.com/misaochan/apps-android-commons/tree/repeat-calls if needed.